# Java Optional - How to convert one type of list to another

Tags: java, stream, mapping, option-type

I have an optional `Optional<TypeA>` from which I can do a `map` function and get `Optional<List<TypeB>>`.

But I would like to now map it to `Optional<List<TypeC>>` and then `orElse()` it. So putting in pseudo code

```
Optional.ofNullable(fooReturnsTypeA()).map(TypeA::barReturnsListTypeB()).{?}.orElse(new ArrayList<TypeC>());
```

I know how to use `map` function, but it's been a while dealing with `Optional` with `map`. So, I might be just staring at the answer. Could someone help me with `{?}` part?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```java
Optional.ofNullable(fooReturnsTypeA())
    .map(TypeA::barReturnsListTypeB())
    .map(typeBList->typeBList
        .stream()
        .map(TypeB::barReturnsTypeC)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
    )
    .orElse(new ArrayList<TypeC>())
```

This basically creates a new `Stream` in `.map` and uses it to convert all elements of `TypeB` to `TypeC` (assuming `TypeB` has a method `barReturnsTypeC` without parameters that returns an instance of `TypeC`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use another `map` and write method to convert `List<TypeB>` to `List<TypeC>`.

You're code will look like this:

```
    Optional.ofNullable(fooReturnsTypeA())
    .map(TypeA::barReturnsListTypeB())
    .map(this::convert)
    .orElse(new ArrayList<TypeC>());
```

And your method to convert:

```
    private List<TypeC> convert(List<TypeB> list) {
    // conversion logic
    // return List<TypeC>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would replace the `orElse` with `orElseGet`. Depending on your code, using `orElseGet` instead of `orElse` can improve your performance. The parameter of `orElse` is evaluated even when the `Optional` is non-empty. On the other hand, the parameter of `orElseGet` is evaluated only when the `Optional` is empty. In your specific case, you may be instantiating unnecessary `ArrayList`s. From the Javadoc:

> Supplier method passed as an argument is only executed when an
> Optional value is not present.

You can also dismiss the `{?}` by using a `stream` in the `map`.

```
Optional.ofNullable(fooReturnsTypeA())
    .map(typeA -> typeA.barReturnsListTypeB().stream()
            .map(TypeB::barReturnsTypeC).collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .orElseGet(() -> new ArrayList<TypeC>());
```

Note: see [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional-or-else-vs-or-else-get) for more information about the difference between `orElse` and `orElseGet`.